# Matlab Error 'Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.'

Tags: matlab, matrix, ode

I know this problem comes up a lot on here and I've read through many threads but am still stuck on my specific problem. I'm using a mass matrix with ode function to solve 4 equations simultaneously, 2 algebraic and 2 differential:

```
function ade

% Equation set
% y(1)== radius 1, y(2)== concentration Cc
% y(3)== radius 2  y(4)== concentration Cc2
%==========================================================================
clc
close all

M = [1 0 0 0
     0 0 0 0
     0 0 1 0
     0 0 0 0];

options = odeset('Mass',M);   
y0= [1,1,1,1];
tspan = [0:1:1440];
[t,y]= ode15s(@equations,tspan,y0,options);

function mainequations = equations (t, y)
m = 18;
m2 = 599;
ro = 1000;
ro2 = 1050;
k = 0.085;
k2 = 0.085;
theta = 46/8;
theta2 = 46/8;
De = 7.65*10^-14;
Cb = 0.993;
R = 8.29*10^-7;

alpha = (m*k)/ro;
alpha1 = (m2*k2)/ro2;
beta = (theta*k*y(2))/De;
beta2 = (theta2*k2*y(4))/De;

mainequations = [-alpha*y(2)
                 y(4) - y(2)-(beta * y(1)^2 *(1/y(1) - y(3)))
                 -alpha1*y(4)
                 Cb - y(4) -(beta * y(1)^2 + beta2*(y(3))^2)*(1/y(3) - 1/R)];
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is in the equations at the bottom, I'm guessing one is the wrong size, but when debugging all the y values are the same size i.e. 4x1. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Ok turns out the spaces in my equations meant matlab thought I was adding extra columns, therefore making them different sizes. I've got around that now, but am still getting an error saying this DEA has an index greater than 1, tried fiddling with the constants to no avail, anyone know what to do now?

Comment: Is your second equation correct? Would it not be better to avoid the division as `y(4) - y(2) - beta * y(1) *(1 - y(1) * y(3))`?